# EF/CD how to override Index attribute?

Tags: inheritance, indexing, ef-code-first

I have a project where I've used inheritance when building a Code first data model. The things is that all my entity types needs a common "contextual id", represented as a string:

```
public class EBaseGenericEntity
{
    :
    [Index("IX_Cid", IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual string Cid { get; set; }
    :
}
```

As you can see the "Cid" property should always hold unique values. The thing is: There is one entity type who's 'Cid' value doesn't have to be unique so I thought this would work:

```
public class EEntityInfo : EBaseGenericEntity
{
    :
    [Index("IX_Cid", IsUnique = false)]
    public override string Cid { get; set; }
    :
}
```

Alas, this makes Entity Framework stumble, complaining about:

Property 'Cid' on type 'EEntityInfo' is attributed with two IndexAttributes with name 'IX_Cid' that contain conflicting configuration: 
    Index attribute property 'IsUnique' = 'True' conflicts with index attribute property 'IsUnique' = 'False'.

Is it not possible to override a property's attribute like this in EF/CF?

EDIT:

Just to make sure the problem isn't about how IndexAttribute is declared to support inheritance (`AttributeUsage.Inherited`) I also tried declaring a derived version with a different AttributeUsage:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class IndexedAttribute : IndexAttribute
{
    public IndexedAttribute(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }
}
```

And then using it instead of the 'normal' IndexAttribute:

```
public class EBaseGenericEntity
{
    :
    [Indexed("IX_Cid", IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual string Cid { get; set; }
    :
}

public class EEntityInfo : EBaseGenericEntity
{
    :
    [Indexed("IX_Cid", IsUnique = false)]
    public override string Cid { get; set; }
    :
}
```

This did not help however. I find it odd that EF can find the Indexed custom attribute despite its (non-inheritable) usage. Could it be that a derived custom attribute also cannot override its AttributeUsage?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this.  As there's just a single entity with this problem, I would suggest:

- Define a base entity for your common fields
- Define an inherited base entity with the Cid field and unique index attribute, and use this on most types
- Derive your `EEntityInfo` from the first base entity

You can also define an interface containing the Cid so that you can use common syntax across the types if you need.

Comment: Yes, I considered that but I have quite a lot of code (including several generic methods) that relies on the inheritance relationship of my entities. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That was why I suggested using an interface - if you can make those methods work on the interface instead, you'll only need that to be applied on EBaseGenericEntity and EEntityInfo.  I've used this approach in my projects when I need inheritance-like support with different base classes.

Comment: Indeed, and I will keep that in mind for future EF/CF projects but I'm a bit too far down the road now for that solution. I managed to fix it eventually by implementing my own db-initializer that honors the "IndexedAttribute" custom attribute while ensuring it isn't inherited for overridden properties. I still think the default implementation (IndexAttribute) is flawed that doesn't allow for overridden attribute usage.